# Rotating A Dial in Android

Tags: android

I need to rotate my image in my on touch listener when the user touches it. I am rotating a dial graphic, so it needs to rotate around its center point. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd refer to the actual android documentation for animation here:   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

As for setting up the rotation in an xml, it will look something like:

```
<set android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate 
       android:fromDegrees="180"
       android:toDegrees="0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:repeatCount="0"
       android:duration="1000">
    </rotate>
</set>
```

That is for a 180 rotation.

Comment: Animation is not correct, it needs to be updated on touch, having that many animation srunning will screw up the app.

Comment: You can have the animation run on touch.  Just call the start() from inside your listener.  What's the problem?  If you have multiple dial graphics, you don't need to define an animation for each.  Just reuse it.  Not sure how any of this will screw up your app.  What else are you doing in there?  Post some code.